# Trim array after matching two strings

Tags: swift, swift4

i want to know how to trim array by matching two string. There is one big array and i have to trim that array by matching starting string and end string.

I have this array.

```
var timeArray = ["1AM",  "2AM",  "3AM",  "4AM",  "5AM",  "6AM", "7AM",
                 "8AM",  "9AM",  "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM",
                 "3PM",  "4PM",  "5PM",  "6PM",  "7PM",  "8PM", "9PM", 
                 "10PM", "11PM", "12AM"]
```

I get two string i.e. **Opening Hour** and **Closing Hour**. These value are picked from PickerView and i need to trim the array according to opening hour and closing hour.

Suppose i got "6AM" as opening hour and "10PM" as closing hour from picker view then my new array should be

```
var newtimeArray = ["6AM", "7AM", "8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM",
                    "1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM",  "6PM",  "7PM", 
                    "8PM", "9PM", "10PM"]
```

What is the nice way to do this. Actually i need these new array to show in cell of table view. The number of cell in table view depends on these new Array.

Comment: What happens if you open at `"2PM"` and close at `"2AM"`?

Comment: oh yeah, the new array should be ````var newtimeArray = ["2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM", "6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM","10PM", "11PM", "12AM", "1AM", "2AM" ]````

Comment: @vacawama Help me out how can i achieve this new array :(

Comment: Hi @JackNelda, people might be better able to help you if you add some code showing what you've already tried to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`firstIndex(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex) to find the indices of the opening and closing times, and then use those indices to find subarrays of the original array to construct the answer:

```
func makeTimeArray(open: String, close: String) -> [String] {
    let timeArray = ["1AM", "2AM", "3AM", "4AM", "5AM", "6AM", "7AM", "8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM", "6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM","10PM", "11PM", "12AM"]

    guard let openIdx = timeArray.firstIndex(of: open),
          let closeIdx = timeArray.firstIndex(of: close)
        else { return [] }

    if openIdx <= closeIdx {
        // straightforward case
        return Array(timeArray[openIdx...closeIdx])
    } else {
        // handle wraps past midnight
        return Array(timeArray[openIdx...] + timeArray[...closeIdx])
    }
}
```

---

**Examples:**

```
print(makeTimeArray(open: "8PM", close: "2AM"))
```

> ```
> ["8PM", "9PM", "10PM", "11PM", "12AM", "1AM", "2AM"]
> ```

```
print(makeTimeArray(open: "2PM", close: "2PM"))
```

> ```
> ["2PM"]
> ```

```
print(makeTimeArray(open: "8AM", close: "2PM"))
```

> ```
> ["8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM"]
> ```

```
print(makeTimeArray(open: "13AM", close: "8PM"))
```

> ```
> []
> ```

Comment: Maybe `lastIndex(of:)` would be more appropriate for `closeIdx`. `timeArray` should better be outside the function to not to have to create a new one each time the function is called.

Comment: It doesn’t matter which function you use to find the index, unless perhaps you’re thinking the closing time will be nearer to the end of the array than the beginning? Compilers are pretty Smart, and we’ve given Swift all the information it needs to not create the constant array each time. I’d be curious to know if moving the array outside the function would have any performance difference for an app compiled for release mode.

Comment: You're right about the second point. As to the first, I think it would be faster in a *sorted* array

Comment: We’re talking about optimizing a function that gets called once when the user has made two selections from the U/I. The slow thing here is the human, and I wouldn’t worry about optimizing a function like this unless it is called millions of time in a short period.